# Print count of inserted documents after insertMany operation in Node

Tags: node.js, json, mongodb, bulkinsert

This script is working fine but i just want the count of inserted documents to be also shown in console on a success insert operation.

```
app.post('/',uploads.single('csv'),(req,res)=>{      
csv()  
.fromFile(req.file.path)  
.then((jsonObj)=>{  
     csvModel.insertMany(jsonObj,(err,data)=>{  
            if(err){  
                console.log(err);  
            }else{  
                console.log('Documents Inserted Successfully');
                res.redirect('/');  
            }  
     });  
   });  
});
```

Comment: it will return `insertedIds`, array of inserted documents ids, console `data.insertedIds.length`

Comment: Error ``` TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at C:\Users\User\cogazzimport\app.js:63:46 ```

Comment: just console `data` what are you getting.

Comment: its a whole json multidimensional array

Comment: i think i should go with data.length and yeah its working!

Comment: @turivishal post an answer i will accept it

Comment: i am considering this as typo, you can answer your self or you can delete your question.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the correct answer was to get the length of data

`console.log(data.length);`